# Better calculator than GNOME Calculator

Tags: gnome, 15.04

I was using GNOME Calculator. Is there a one that doesn't change its width once I enter numbers, like the Ubuntu standard-one?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could [file a bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-calculator/-/issues), but I couldn't reproduce it on 3.36.0. Maybe is resolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure; try [galculator](http://galculator.mnim.org/).

```bash
sudo apt-get install galculator
```

[image: Screen shot of galculator application]

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you use [SpeedCrunch](https://heldercorreia.bitbucket.io/speedcrunch/).

It has all you need and more: scientific calculator, clean history and even a book with constants and functions.

[image: SpeedCrunch with constants]

Answer (score 0):

I would refer to [Qalculate](https://qalculate.github.io/) (and `qalc`, the command line version of Qalculate). I shared the command-line interface so that people who don't like GUI interfaces and prefer command-line (CLI).